# Issue with xmlHttp.send() method

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to load an XML file and get its DOM object. I think the error is with this code:

```
// Takes an XML document and loads it and returns a DOM of the document
function loadXMLDoc(filepath)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else // code for IE6, IE5
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", filepath, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    return xmlDoc;
}
```

The code stops executing at `xmlhttp.send()`. I get the following error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://localhost/Users/Dylan/programming/projects/personalpage/resources/cool-data.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

This highlights the `xmlhttp.send()` line. I had this working before and I don't think I made any changes to the file. The only difference I know is that I am now executing this on my local machine. Before I was using an IDE hosted online (cloud9) so the files were all remote on a web server. Also, it worked on Windows and I'm now on a Mac.

Edit: I called the function with the argument: `"../resources/items-data.xml"`
and all of my work is on my local machine. Equal level directories are `js`, `html`, `css`, and `resources`.

Comment: you cann't load a local xml file my file://url instead try https://localhost/url... hope this helps

Comment: With which argument did you call your function and from which website? XMLHTTPRequest is supposed to enforce strict same-origin rules.

Comment: actually if you are still working in localhost, same-origin policies would not be enforced..

Comment: @Benny: Good point. We certainly need to know from where the OP made the request.

Comment: @Benny: same-origin policy *is* enforced, see my anwser.

Comment: @Kerrek I updated my question to answer your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XHR locally (in `file:` origin), but there is a catch: Google Chrome and Firefox (I believe) will prevent you from accessing files other than the files in the same directory with the html file. That is

`file://localhost/Users/Dylan/programming/projects/personalpage/index.htm`

can access

`file://localhost/Users/Dylan/programming/projects/personalpage/abc.xml`, or 
`file://localhost/Users/Dylan/programming/projects/personalpage/abc.json.js`

but not

`file://localhost/Users/Dylan/programming/projects/personalpage/resources/cool-data.xml`, or
`file://localhost/etc/passwd`

This restriction has only be added to recent version. I guess that's the reason you didn't find out in the first place.

P.S. Next time, do everybody a favor by using jQuery or other Javascript library rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe for now I'll just place them in the same directory. I am doing this as a learning exercise, as I'm just getting into Javascript and want to get some stuff working before learning a bunch of APIs.